# How to play multiple frequencies simultaneously using the winsound module

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I am creating a simple music playing program using the `Beep` function in the `winsound` module. I am trying to play multiple "Beeps" at once, trying things such as

```
from winsound import Beep
Beep(440, 2000) + Beep(330, 2000)
```

and

```
from winsound import Beep
Beep(440, 2000), Beep(330, 2000)
```

but none of them work. I know this probably has a really simple answer, but I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: The [`winsound.Beep()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/PC/winsound.c) function simply calls the Windows API [`Beep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which doesn't provide a way to do it multiple times simultaneously. I tried playing more than one .wav sound file at the same time using `winsound.SND_ASYNC`, but was unable to get more than one going at once either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import winsound  
from multiprocessing import Process
def func1():
     winsound.PlaySound("C:\samplepath\soundfile1.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME|winsound.SND_NOWAIT)

def func2():
     winsound.PlaySound("C:\samplepath\soundfile2.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME|winsound.SND_NOWAIT)

if __name__=='__main__':
     p1 = Process(target = func1)
     p1.start()
     p2 = Process(target = func2)
     p2.start()
```

This should allow you to play sounds simultaneously (although I have not tested it with beeps).

Comment: This will not work with the `winsound.Beep` sound, only the first one can be heard. Off-topic: indenting Python code 5 spaces is fairly unusual. I suggest you read (and start following) the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Also, the file paths shown are invalid because they contain backslashes which have not been escaped properly.

Answer (score -1):

I can not play with `winsound` at this monment, but guessing you can use `threading` module to achieve your goal, like this:

```
from winsound import Beep
import threading

# Start multi threads, so `Beep` will run simultaneously instead of blocking
threading.Thread(target=Beep, args=(440, 2000)).start()
threading.Thread(target=Beep, args=(330, 2000)).start()
```

For more details on the threading module, you can go to [the document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Comment: How about [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module? you can give it a try.

Comment: This does not appear to work. Have you had a chance to try this out and create a working version?